# Full-width, responsive, grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, responsive-design

Would anyone be able to explain to me how this page functions?

http://wexley-demo.squarespace.com/

I see that there's javascript, but don't understand it.

Also is this the most simple way to achieve this effects? – scaling, realigning content that stays in a perfect grid layout at any width.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both Media queries and jQuery mobile to design your application.

jQuery mobile is for design (Responsive design) and media queries for applying the styles.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to learn all about responsive design, then look into Mobile First vs Desktop First approach, then you need to think about Adaptive vs Responsive, if you pick Responsive then you need to think about Responsive Plus.  On top of all that you need to think about fluid vs static layout, touch vs no-touch.  Need to learn what media-queries are in css, figure out a strategy where media-queries don't work.  Think about the kind of assets that you are sending to different client environment and how you do it.

Best bet, if you need this done professionally, correctly and correctly, hire a developer who knows how to do all of this already.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries i can suggest is the best solution for responsive design.

Let me give you a simple code for responsivenes based on page width

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #p1{
   color:red;
   }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
   #p1{
   color:blue;
   }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p id="p1" media="(max-width: 800px)">Hi , This text colour change according to browser size.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

you can find more tutorial simply [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)